# Sprite Kit - Keep playing audio when changing scene

Tags: ios, avfoundation, sprite-kit

I used this code to loop a audio file:

```
// *** In your interface... ***
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

...

AVAudioPlayer *testAudioPlayer;

// *** Implementation... ***

// Load the audio data
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_name" ofType:@"wav"];
NSData *sampleData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
NSError *audioError = nil;

// Set up the audio player
testAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sampleData error:&audioError];

if(audioError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"An audio error occurred: \"%@\"", audioError);
}
else {
    [testAudioPlayer setNumberOfLoops: -1];
    [testAudioPlayer play];
}
```

But when the scene is changed, the audio stops. Is there a way to keep it playing in the background during all scenes?

Comment: It depends on what's in charge of running the audio clip in question.  UIViewController or SKScene...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have set the audio player up at a level above the SKScene, I did this in one of my Sprite Kit apps by having the UIViewController play the music, then when I swapped SKScenes the music continued to play.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your main SKScene and add this:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"YourFileName.extension" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

It will keep playing forever, even when you transition scenes.

Peace.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this. Here's is the SpriteKit Swift 3.0 version of @user3504848 `self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("YourFileName.extension", waitForCompletion: false))`